# Is infrared active phonon the reason why infrared is not passing through walls?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, solid-state-physics

I did some research on why infrared is not passing through walls.I learnt about infrared active phonons which are responsible for scattering in solids.It cannot be raman scattering,rayleigh scattering,Infrared scattering due to vibrational modes which causes infrared to not pass through walls.So is infrared optical photons the cause for this property of walls.

Comment: Please somebody answer.

Comment: It is both molecular vibrational modes and phonons, involving polar bonds. An example in molecules are CO$_2$ and water molecules as greenhouse gases.